# Difference between Skulk and Sneak

Tags: verbs, differences

I am wondering what are the differences between "skulk" and "sneak"?

I looked on oxford dictionary:

**Skulk**: "Keep out of sight, typically with a sinister or cowardly motive."

**Sneak**: "Move or go in a furtive or stealthy way."

They sound the same. Are they different at all? Some concrete examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in your dictionary:

*To sneak* means to **move** in a certain manner.

*To skulk* means to **hide** in a certain manner.

**Examples**

John saw Mary sneaking **through** the bushes.  (Mary is moving)

John saw Mary skulking **in** the bushes.  (Mary is hiding)

Comment: Another dictionary quote to support this? (Dictionary.com might be your best bet for 'skulk'; Collins is 50-50, and M-W might not help your claim.)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Didn't the OP's dictionary show this? *Skulk: keep out of sight*, *Sneak: Move or go*.  The first doesn't *require* movement (although it isn't precluded entirely), the second *is* a form of movement.

Comment: 'Another' demands that there was already one mention. Answers on ELU should be better than this, and you know it. The caveat (M-W's counterexample) and no explanation of which sense of 'implies' you're using make this answer far from optimal.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I've edited. Any better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any significant difference in *meaning*. But ***skulk*** is [a lot less common today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skulking%20around%2Csneaking%20around&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3), as that linked NGram chart shows, so unless you specifically *want* that "dated" association, I'd stick with ***sneak***.

There are some syntactic differences, though. Per [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&content=he%20skulked%20out%2Che%20snuck%20out%2Che%20sneaked%20out&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20skulked%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20snuck%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20sneaked%20out%3B%2Cc0), both past tense verb forms commonly occur in, for example, ***he sneaked / snuck out***, but you would very rarely encounter ***he skulked out***. This is nothing to do with any *semantic* difference relating to physical movement as opposed to appearance. It's just a matter of established acceptable syntax, as shown by the fact that both verbs in ***to sneak / skulk about*** mean exactly the same thing and both occur fairly often - but *to skulk **out*** (or [***in***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=he%20skulked%20in%2Che%20snuck%20in%2Che%20sneaked%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20skulked%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20snuck%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20sneaked%20in%3B%2Cc0)) is just unfamiliar, so it's a bit "awkward".

---

EDIT: It's not much of a semantic difference, but I'll just say that ***to skulk*** can often carry stronger associations with ***keep your head down, maintain a low profile***.

I support the above assertion with [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=skulking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes%2Csneaking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskulking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csneaking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cskulking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csneaking%20around%20in%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0), showing that both verbs often occur with ***sneaking / skulking around in the bushes***. People are usually taller than bushes, so that context definitely implies keeping your head down, as well as "hiding" behind bushes. And the fact that the verbs are *equally* common with (low-profile) bushes, whereas in more general contexts ***sneaking around*** is almost three times as common as ***skulking around*** suggests to me the latter has stronger associations with *being near the ground*.

Personally, I might be inclined to say my cat is ***skulking about*** if she's trying to keep [her head, back, and tail] as low as possible while creeping / sneaking up on some hapless prey in the garden.